# Firebase source maps crashes cordova app (IOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, firebase

I just upgraded Firebase JavaScript SDK to the new version that support source maps. Link: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Every time I run the app and inspect the app with safari debugger i get the following error:

```
file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/ID/Flare%20BETA.app/www/lib/firebase/firebase-app.js.map
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server
```